# is there a torrent to download rosGroovyGalapagos.ova?

Tags: ros, virtualbox, download

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Spect. ROS Team,

Downloding rosGroovyGalapagos.ova file always fail...

Can you provide a torrent link to download this file?

Regards,
Giacomo Stelluti Scala

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/75136/is-there-a-torrent-to-download-rosgroovygalapagos.ova?/) by [Giacomo S. S.](https://answers.ros.org/users/6205/giacomo-s.-s./) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-08-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Trye saving the file from http://nootrix.com/2013/01/virtualized-ros-groovy/ by rightclicking and download file as.. or save file as.

---

Originally posted by [rdehond](https://answers.ros.org/users/6766/rdehond/) with karma: 16 on 2013-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0